# Simple Mongoid Validation for create! - how to display error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Rails 3 with mongoid 2 and have a simple question regarding mongoid validation.

```
if @forum.topics.create!(name: params[:topic][:name])
   # success, do something
else
  #should handle errors but doesn't
    render 'new'
end
```

If I use the .create! method, it runs validations on a mongoid model class correctly, but it is not getting to the else block to display the error.  Instead it returns a rails error page saying...

Mongoid::Errors::Validations in TopicsController#create

Validation failed - Name can't be blank.

That's good, but how do I display that in a view instead of getting an ugly rails error message page?

Comment: try with `@forum.topics.new(name: params[:topic][:name]).save` in the if condition?

Comment: that actually works Yoshiji if you want to put that as an answer i will accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
new_topic = @forum.topics.new(name: params[:topic][:name])
if new_topic.save
   # success, do something
else
  render 'new', errors: new_topic.errors.full_messages
end
```

with this way you will have the local variable `errors` which is a Hash formated like following:

```
new_topic.errors.full_messages # => ["\"Name\" can't be blank"]
```

Comment: It's an array, not a hash, no?

Answer (score 0):

you can rescue the Mongoid::Errors::Validations and use it's instance method to get the errors

```
new_topic = @forum.topics.new(name: params[:topic][:name])
new_topic.create!
rescue Mongoid::Errors::Validations => e
  summary = e.summary
  problem = e.problem
  res = e.resolution
```

using the above error messages you can display the error

Documentaion link
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/6.2/api/Mongoid/Errors/Validations.html